# Value not being set on input from Angular 2 Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have an input which I want to populate with an Angular 2 Bootstrap datepicker. When the page opens, the value is initiated with today's date by using `value="{{ getStartDate() | date:'fullDate'}}"`. But when I click the button and open the datepicker and choose a new date, the value does not populate the input. Also I can no longer click the button again to close the datepicker.

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div>
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!secondForm.controls['startDate'].valid && secondForm.controls['startDate'].touched}">
  <input value="{{ getStartDate() | date:'fullDate'}}" style="width:250px" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="secondForm.controls['startDate']">
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <ngb-datepicker *ngIf="startCheck==true;" [(ngModel)]="dt" class="dropdown-toggle" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" style="position:absolute; z-index:1"></ngb-datepicker>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn icon-calendar" (click)="showDatePick()"></button>
<button type="button" class="btn icon-search" [disabled]="!secondForm.valid"></button>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
selector: 'calendar-pick',
styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
templateUrl: './calendarpick.component.html'
})

export class CalendarPickComponent {
public dt:Date = new Date();
public startCheck: boolean = false;
//Might need to change this to complexForm, not sure yet
secondForm : FormGroup;

public constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
this.secondForm = fb.group({
  'startDate' : [this.dt, Validators.required]
})
this.secondForm.valueChanges.subscribe( (form: any) => {
    console.log('form changed to:', form);
  }
);
}

public getStartDate():number {
return this.dt && this.dt.getTime() || new Date().getTime();
}

public showDatePick():void {
if (this.startCheck == false){
  this.startCheck = true;
} else {
  this.startCheck = false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error on the console?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi sorry, yes Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)
    at https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js:7:2344
    at https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js:7:10382
    at https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js:7:12447

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error but you have an starting point for looking, it seems that something is missed to make tooltips happy

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I was able to add the script tag in my `index.html` to get rid of that error. Still getting the same problem with the `input` and `datepicker` though

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I changed `[(ngModel)]="dt"` to `[ngModel]="dt"` and added `(ngModelChange)="getStartDate($event)"` and the `input` still won't populate, but clicking the button that opens the `datepicker` again will now close it like I want it to

Comment: I'm sorry but my 2 cents for now is the suggestion for checking the console for errors. I'm not familiar enough with the control to suggest any tweak. I know you have examples on library repo. Have you checked if any example is similar to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ng-bootstrap datepicker's model is not a Date() object it is an NgbDateStruct which consists of {month, day, year}

To get the desired behavior, then, the code looks like:

```
import {DatePipe} from "@angular/common";

@Component({providers: [DatePipe]})

public constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private datePipe: DatePipe)
public dt: NgbDateStruct;
<...>
public getStartDate():number {
let timestamp = this.dt != null ? new Date(this.dt.year, this.dt.month-1, this.dt.day).getTime() : new Date().getTime();
this.secondForm.controls['startDate'].setValue(this.datePipe.transform(timestamp, 'fullDate'));
}
```

The markup changes to:
`<input style="width:250px" [value]="getStartDate()" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="secondForm.controls['startDate']">`

Here's the complete plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zqGpoJZ1psKmST0S7Ix0?p=preview

Note that the ng-bootstrap team's month index is 0 based and not one based which is maddening when using the native Date object in combination with the NgbDate.

Also, the way it's written with the default value being new Date().getTime() means that you never have a blank value which may/may not be desired. And it's always dirty and valid.

Comment: The input from the datepicker shows up now but getting console error `Type 'number | Date' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'number'.` Also, now my form validation does not recognize that there is input when I choose a date, so my button stays disabled unless I manually type something there. Just like in the plunker example.

Comment: Updated to so the form control is properly catching the value being set.

Comment: How can I initialize `startDate` and `endDate` to something else, or nothing? I tried `'startDate' : [null, Validators.required]` but `DatePipe` gets in the way of that. Also, using `DatePipe` doesn't allow me to bank the input blank if I want, it always stays populated.